# How do I remove delete button in listview for delphi firemonkey android platform?

Tags: android, delphi, listview, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

i am seeing delete button via multi touch tap on listview items in my application.

there is deletebuttontext property but there isn't delete button visible false option property for listview.

i don't want use this option in listview.

How do I remove delete button in listview for delphi firemonkey android platform?

Also listview editmode property false but deleting my items via this delete button.

Comment: Delete button appears when swipe? or its always visible?

Comment: Yes delete button appears when swipe. it is'nt always visible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set the property `CanSwipeDelete` from your `ListView` to `false`